Scoping RBAC "Search Service Contributor" to an index in Azure AI Search Service does not allow index creation of that index
Azure Search Index Scoped RBAC Bug Minimum Working Example
You will need an Azure Search Service and two accounts.  An admin account and a service account that you can change permissions on at the subscription, resource group, resource, and index levels.
The jupyter notebook shows that when the service account's Roles are scoped to the index, index creation (of that index) is forbidden, whereas index deletion is allowed.  This is unexpected behavior, as the service account should (in my view) be allowed to create the index it is scoped to.
Is this a bug?
#%% md
## Azure Search Index Scoped RBAC Bug Minimum Working Example

You will need an Azure Search Service and two accounts.  An admin account and a service account that you can change permissions on at the subscription, resource group, resource, and index levels.

The notebook shows that when the service account's Roles are scoped to the index, index creation (of that index) is forbidden, whereas index deletion is allowed.  This is unexpected behavior, as the service account should (in my view) be allowed to create the index it is scoped to.
#%%
import dotenv
import os

dotenv.load_dotenv(".env.rbac-bug")

ENDPOINT = os.getenv("ENDPOINT")
INDEX_NAME = os.getenv("INDEX_NAME")
SUBSCRIPTION = os.getenv("SUBSCRIPTION")
RESOURCE_GROUP = os.getenv("RESOURCE_GROUP")
SEARCH_SERVICE = os.getenv("SEARCH_SERVICE")
SERVICE_PRINCIPAL = os.getenv("SERVICE_PRINCIPAL")
PASSWORD = os.getenv("PASSWORD")
TENANT_ID = os.getenv("TENANT_ID")


#%%
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.search.documents.indexes import SearchIndexClient
from azure.search.documents.indexes.models import SearchIndex
from azure.core.exceptions import ResourceNotFoundError

def get_search_index_client(endpoint):
    credential = AzureCliCredential()
    !az account show
    # Create the SearchIndexClient
    return SearchIndexClient(endpoint=endpoint, credential=credential)

# Function to check if an index exists and create it if it does not
def ensure_index_exists(index_name, search_index_client):
    try:
        # Attempt to retrieve the index
        index = search_index_client.get_index(index_name)
        print(f"Index '{index_name}' exists.")
    except ResourceNotFoundError:
        # Index does not exist, create it
        print(f"Index '{index_name}' does not exist. Creating index...")
        index = SearchIndex(name=index_name, fields=[
            {"name": "id", "type": "Edm.String", "key": True, "searchable": False},
            {"name": "content", "type": "Edm.String"}
        ])
        search_index_client.create_index(index)
        print(f"Index '{index_name}' created successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to check or create or delete index '{index_name}': {e}")


#%%
# Login with your admin account
!az login
#%%
# Create the index using admin account
admin_search_index_client = get_search_index_client(ENDPOINT)
ensure_index_exists(INDEX_NAME, admin_search_index_client)
#%%
# IMPORTANT!  Manually delete roles for the service principal.  When you are done, you the output of all these commands should be "[]"

subscription_scope = f"/subscriptions/{SUBSCRIPTION}"
resource_group_scope = f"{subscription_scope}/resourceGroups/{RESOURCE_GROUP}"
resource_scope = f"{resource_group_scope}/providers/Microsoft.Search/searchServices/{SEARCH_SERVICE}"
index_scope = f"{resource_scope}/indexes/{INDEX_NAME}"

role_search_index_data_contributor = "search index data contributor"
role_search_service_contributor = "search service contributor"
#%%
# Some typical roles to delete.  If they delete succesfully they should have no output.  Otherwise might have no matched assignments, which is fine too.

!az role assignment delete --assignee $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL --role "search index data contributor" --scope $index_scope
!az role assignment delete --assignee $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL --role "search service contributor" --scope $index_scope
!az role assignment delete --assignee $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL --role "search index data contributor" --scope $resource_scope
!az role assignment delete --assignee $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL --role "search service contributor" --scope $resource_scope
#%%

print(f"Scope: {subscription_scope}")
!az role assignment list --assignee $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL --scope $subscription_scope
#%%

print(f"Scope: {resource_group_scope}")
!az role assignment list --assignee $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL --scope $resource_group_scope
#%%

print(f"Scope: {resource_scope}")
!az role assignment list --assignee $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL --scope $resource_scope
#%%

print(f"Scope: {index_scope}")
!az role assignment list --assignee $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL --scope $index_scope

#%% md

### Assign roles.  Choose the scope you wish to test.

#%%
!az role assignment create --assignee $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL --role "search index data contributor" --scope $index_scope
# !az role assignment create --assignee $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL --role "search index data contributor" --scope $resource_scope

!az role assignment create --assignee $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL --role "search service contributor" --scope $index_scope
# !az role assignment create --assignee $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL --role "search service contributor" --scope $resource_scope


#%%
# Login as the service principal
!az login --service-principal -u $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL -p $PASSWORD --tenant $TENANT_ID
#%%
search_index_client = get_search_index_client(ENDPOINT)
search_client = search_index_client.get_search_client(index_name=INDEX_NAME)
#%% md
### You may need to wait several minutes for the new roles to be applied
#%%
# List the indexes in the search service
# Requires the service principal to have the "search service contributor" role at the resource level.
# Should be forbidden if this role is scoped to an index.
try:
    indexes = search_index_client.list_indexes()
    print("Indexes in the search service:")
    for index in indexes:
        print(f" - {index.name}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Failed to list indexes: {e}")


#%%
# Ensure the index exists.  Assuming it does, this should succeed with "search service contributor" role scoped to the index.
ensure_index_exists(INDEX_NAME, search_index_client)
#%%
# Try to get the index details.  Should succeed with "search service contributor" role scoped to the index.
try:
    index = search_index_client.get_index(INDEX_NAME)
    print(f"Index details: {index}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Failed to get index details: {e}")
#%%
# Try to perform a search operation.  Should succeed with "search index data contributor" role scoped to the index.  Output will be empty, since the index is empty.
try:
    results = search_client.search("search text")
    for result in results:
        print(result)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Failed to perform search: {e}")
#%%
# Delete the index.  This should succeed with "search service contributor" role scoped to the index.
search_index_client.delete_index(INDEX_NAME)
#%%
# Having deleted the index, it should be recreated.  This should succeed with "search service contributor" role scoped to the index. 
# HOWEVER, it fails with forbidden.
ensure_index_exists(INDEX_NAME, search_index_client)



When the index got deleted, I imagine the role assignment is deleted as well

@Thomas good though, but I think I disproved this by trying the following.  Login in to admin account, delete INDEX_NAME, remove all RBACs from SP, re-add index-scoped RBACs, verify the presence of both roles.  I then re-logged in to the admin account, added and then deleted INDEX_NAME, and checked for both roles again (they are present).  Also re-checked the behaviour described in my post.    It would appear to me that deleting the index does not change any roles (thankfully, because that would really mess me up :D)
